# Express - Find an object in MongoDB by id and save its data to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two models: Meal and Ingredient. Here are the schemas:

```
const mealSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { type: String, required: false },
    ingredients: [{
        ingredient: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Ingredient' },
        amount: { type: Number, required: true }
    }],
})

const ingredientSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    unit: { type: String, required: true },
    category: { type: String, required: false },
    is_vege: { type: Boolean, required: true }
});
```

When I create the meal, I provide the ingredients as an array in POST request body.

```
const createMeal = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { title, ingredients } = req.body;

    // ingredientArray consists of objects with two keys:
    // <String> ingredient - id of the associated ingredient in database
    // <Number> amount - amount of the ingredient
    ingredientArray = JSON.parse(ingredients)

    const createdMeal = new Meal({
        title,
        image: req.file.path,
        ingredients: ingredientArray
    });

    try {
        await createdMeal.save();
    } catch (err) {
        const error = new HttpError('Error occurred, try again later', 500);
        return next(error);
    }

    res.status(201).json(createdMeal);
}
```

This is the object that is created:

```
{
    "_id": "62ea4531bd7e04fa740e2fee",
    "title": "Spaghetti",
    "image": "uploads\\images\\8da09ec6-3684-4af5-a513-f90155ddafd8.jpeg",
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "ingredient": "62ea37251212c738a0ce9cee",
            "amount": 100,
            "_id": "62ea4531bd7e04fa740e2fef",
            "id": "62ea4531bd7e04fa740e2fef"
        },
        {
            "ingredient": "62ea371ab9392f3e0107c541",
            "amount": 10,
            "_id": "62ea4531bd7e04fa740e2ff0",
            "id": "62ea4531bd7e04fa740e2ff0"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "62ea4531bd7e04fa740e2fee"
}
```

I need my "ingredients" list to find the actual ingredient in the database and save its complete data so that the result would look something like this:

```
"ingredients": [
    {
        "ingredient": "62ea37251212c738a0ce9cee",
        "amount": 100,
        "name": "Pasta",
        "unit": "g",
        "category": "pastas",
        "is_vege": true,
        "_id": "62ea4531bd7e04fa740e2fef",
        "id": "62ea4531bd7e04fa740e2fef"
    },
    {
        "ingredient": "62ea371ab9392f3e0107c541",
        "amount": 200,
        "name": "Tomato",
        "unit": "g",
        "category": "vegetables",
        "is_vege": true,
        "_id": "62ea4531bd7e04fa740e2ff0",
        "id": "62ea4531bd7e04fa740e2ff0"
    }
]
```

EDIT: Ideally, the ingredient should be found BEFORE saving, because I want to run some calculations before the meal ends up in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It took a single line of code:

```
    let createdMeal = new Meal({
        title,
        image: req.file.path,
        prep_time,
        ingredients: ingredientArray
    });

    createdMeal = await createdMeal.populate({ path: 'ingredients.ingredient' });
```

Documentation:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html